# why the timer doesn't decrement?

Tags: swing

here's the code

```
public class TimeClass implements ActionListener{
    int timerCounter;

    public TimeClass(int timerCounter){
        this.timerCounter = timerCounter; 
    }

    public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent time){

        timerCounter--;
        if(timerCounter >= 1){
        timeLeft.setText("Time Remaining: " + timerCounter);    
        }else{

            timer.stop();
            timeLeft.setText("Game Over!");
            click.setEnabled(false);    
        }
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
    }   
    }
```

the timer does not decrement.what;s wrong in the code?i need this for my presentation.need this asap. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You implemented the functionality in the wrong method, it should be in `actionPerformed`:

```
@Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent time){

    timerCounter--;
    if(timerCounter >= 1){
    timeLeft.setText("Time Remaining: " + timerCounter);    
    }else{

        timer.stop();
        timeLeft.setText("Game Over!");
        click.setEnabled(false);    
    }
}
```

Using the `@Override` notation when overiding a method will help you avoid such mistakes, as the compiler will warn you when used on non-overwriting method.